# Load double from hexadecimal values in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, label, double, cpu-word

I am trying to load the hexadecimal value of a float from a label. I store it in a label because it's a constant value which I don't want to compute every call to the function.

What I found was doing it like this:

```
x0:  // sqrt(3/5)
    .word 0x3ada5b53
    .word 0x0342423

// And then later down the road do this:
fldd d0,x0;
```

Which sadly seems to not work. How would I go about doing this? Or what would be an easier way of storing these values? Storing the hexadecimal values seems to be the most precise method to me, but as it stands im unable to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly how long "later on down the road" is, if it refuses to assemble (or link) you might be hitting the limit of how far away you can load from. From [some documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473j/dom1361289957202.html):

> *label* must be aligned on a word boundary within ±1KB of the current instruction.

*armasm* has, as for `MOV`, a [`VLDR r, =const` pseudo-op](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473j/dom1361289957882.html) that generates an automatic immediate/literal load as appropriate and generally makes sure literals are kept suitably close by. GNU *as* doesn't seem to have this, but provided you manually arrange for the labels to be close enough, defining data with either `.double` or `.word` generates appropriate code:

```
data1:  .double 0.774596669241483377
        vldr.f64 d0, data1    @ UAL syntax for fldd

data2:  .word   0xf43f7248
        .word   0x3fe8c97e
        vldr.f64 d1, data2
```

Gives:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <data1>:
   0:   f43f7248        .word   0xf43f7248
   4:   3fe8c97e        .word   0x3fe8c97e
   8:   ed1f0b04        vldr    d0, [pc, #-16]  ; 0 <data1>

0000000c <data2>:
   c:   f43f7248        .word   0xf43f7248
  10:   3fe8c97e        .word   0x3fe8c97e
  14:   ed1f1b04        vldr    d1, [pc, #-16]  ; c <data2>
```

which makes me suspect another reason it "doesn't seem to work", since your value of `sqrt(3/5)` looks rather wrong.